Integrating and syncing one instance of Salescloud with two instances of ERP
I would appreciate some advice on how to integrate one instance of Salescloud (and within it Marketing Cloud Engagement) with two separate instances of an Inventory Management App (Cin7) with each being integrated into their own ERP (Xero)
We require two-way synchronization of customer files, inventory and sales, yet we do not want the wrong files syncing with the wrong ERP or duplication.
Background:
We have two nearly identical yet completely separate business entities operating in different geographies, yet they trade under the same branding and share one website, social media accounts, sales channels, etc.
We cannot merge the companies and they must terminate into their own unique ERP for accounting/taxation purposes.
The idea is that when each sale or customer enquiry/file enters Salescloud it is allocated to the relevant company (and salesperson/user) depending on the location it is generated from. Each company has different salespeople, so even if all these files co-mingle inside Salescloud (presumably with some identifier tag to show which company it belongs to) they cannot be co-mingled across companies in the ERP.
In the diagram below we assume the workflow that all inwards communications/sales should flow into Salescloud first and then be synced with ERP, yet we are hoping that some sales can also originate from the ERP and then be synced up to Salescloud (in future we may have integrations direct to the ERP rather than with Salescloud)

We have considered using some kind of tags to help identify which file belongs in which company, though are not sure how this would work if it is even possible?
We have also considered embedding one company inside the other's ERP as a separate branch, yet the work required to then unscramble this into it's own ERP seems unwieldy.
I would be most grateful for any suggestions? Even if it only gets us half way there.
Thanks!

... One possibility we are playing with is whether we put our Woocommerce e-store between Salescloud and our Inventory App. Ie. Then we have one instance of Salescloud integrating with one instance of Woocommerce and then it becomes Woocommerce's problem to integrate with the Inventory App - devilish indeed ;0)
